# Speed up computation of sum from large matrix

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, summation

I have a 3x3 matrix (252^3) of data (densities) and I want to compute a correlation xi from nearest neighbours as well as a sum involving a check whether the density is in a certain bin. The computation works in principle (so for subsamples, when step size is about 10) but is painfully slow. I am not an expert on handling data with Mathematica, so I am pretty sure there is some solution that works way better than my first try. For the correlation function I think that basically need an analogue of AbsoluteCorrelationFunction for my matrix.

```
xi=
   1/3*Sum[data[[i,j,k]] (data[[i + 1,j,k]] + 
          data[[i,j + 1,k]] + 
          data[[i,j,k + 1]]), {i, 1, 251, 1}, {j, 1, 
        251, 1}, {k, 1, 251, 1}]/26^3 - 1;
```

For the following quantity I am not sure if there is another faster Mathematica routine. I need to check whether the density is in a bin of width deltarho around rho and if yes add the values of the neighbouring densities

```
brho[rho_]:=(Sum[If[Abs[data[[i,j,k]] - rho] < 
      deltarho/2, (data[[i + 1,j,k]] + 
       data[[i,j + 1,k]] + 
       data[[i,j,k + 1]]), 0], {i, 1, 251, 1}, {j, 1, 
     251, 1}, {k, 1, 251, 1}]/
   Sum[Boole[
     Abs[data[[i,j,k]] - rho] < deltarho/2], {i, 1, 
     251, 1}, {j, 1, 251, 1}, {k, 1, 251, 1}] - 1)
```

I tried replacing Sum with ParallelSum but at least for the subsample it makes things slower.

Are there any ideas how to speed this up?

Thanks a  lot in advance!

edit: improved readability & corrected typo, thanks to comment of Jason

Comment: Just first impressions - to improve readability in the code for yourself and others, you can replace things like `data[[i]][[j]][[k]] ` with `data[[i,j,k]]` and `, {i, 1, 251, 1}, {j, 1, 251, 1}, {k, 1, 251, 1}]` with `,{i, 251}, {j, 251}, {k, 251}`  but this is just a style point and doesn't address your main question.

Comment: I tried running your definition of `xi` on a random matrix `dims = {251, 251, 251};
data = RandomReal[1, dims];` and it takes **a long time**.  You could get the same thing virtually instantly by a judicious use of `Total` and `RotateLeft` and `Drop`

Comment: Also, Can I assume that `{i, 1, 251, 10}` is a typo in the `brho` code?  It's the only `10` in there so I assume it should be a `1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, basically your code is designed with a less efficient algorithm.

Bear in mind that Mathematica generally treats a matrix the "same" as a number, so don't spend time on computation conducted at the number level.

Then we can convert your code to be running at the matrix level, where the speed is much increased.

```
len = 20;
data = RandomReal[{1, 10}, {len, len, len}];
xi=1/3*Sum[data[[i,j,k]] (data[[i+1,j,k]]+data[[i,j+1,k]]+data[[i,j,k+1]]),{i,len-1},{j,len-1},{k,len-1}]/26^3-1;//AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.030215, Null}*)
xxi=Total@Flatten@(data[[1;;len-1,1;;len-1,1;;len-1]](data[[2;;len,1;;len-1,1;;len-1]]+data[[1;;len-1,2;;len,1;;len-1]]+data[[1;;len-1,1;;len-1,2;;len]]))/3/26^3-1;//AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.00039, Null}*)
xi == xxi
(*True*)
```

Now we increase `len` to 252 as required by your scenario:

```
len = 252;
data = RandomReal[{1, 10}, {len, len, len}];
xxi=Total@Flatten@(data[[1;;len-1,1;;len-1,1;;len-1]](data[[2;;len,1;;len-1,1;;len-1]]+data[[1;;len-1,2;;len,1;;len-1]]+data[[1;;len-1,1;;len-1,2;;len]]))/3/26^3-1;//AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.653753, Null}*)
```

See, the performance is not bad.

I think now you can improve the second part of your problem with the idea above.

Edit:
As for the second part of your problem, there is no need to perform testing over each element: a holistic testing works as well:

```
Clear[brho]
brho[data_List,rho_,deltarho_]:=Module[{c,sum},
c=UnitStep[deltarho/2-Abs[data[[1;;-2,1;;-2,1;;-2]]-rho]];
sum=data[[2;;-1,1;;-2,1;;-2]]+data[[1;;-2,2;;-1,1;;-2]]+data[[1;;-2,1;;-2,2;;-1]];
Total@Flatten[c*sum]/Total@Flatten[c]
]
```

Give it a try:

```
brho[data,10,3]
```

which will give the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much, you are great guys! This runs in 2s now :-) I hope I will be able to generalize this ideas also to the other functions I want to compute and do the error estimation by using subsamples.